# How to run a command at startup with systemd?

Tags: 15.10, startup, systemd, execute-command

I've got a specific command which I want to run at startup, I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18 with `systemd`. But after searching I can only seem to find [ways of doing it through `upstart`](https://askubuntu.com/a/910/364819). So how do you run a command at startup using `systemd`?

Comment: Added systemd method to that question.

Comment: @muru: Good, and I guess that this is a good signpost question to the other question which now has an answer which covers this. :)